# Find a surjective Function f

Tags: functions

I'm trying to find a surjective function f: $\mathbb N^\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb N \times \mathbb Z$ where $\mathbb N^ \mathbb Z $ is the set of all of all functions $\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb N $.

I'm having trouble finding a 'simple' solution and end up with very unelegant and complex functions, but is there a simple example?
I start by composing something of the type $\mathbb f(g(.)) \rightarrow (g(a),g(b))$ , as i have to show that $\mathbb \forall (a,b) \in \mathbb N \times \mathbb Z  \exists g\in \mathbb N^ \mathbb Z : f(g(.)) : (a,b) $

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

Define $\Phi_Z: \Bbb N^{\Bbb Z} \to \Bbb Z$ by
$$
\Phi_Z(g) = \begin{cases}
\min\{g^{-1}(1)\} & g^{-1}(1) \text{ has a minimum}\\
0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Define $\Phi_N: \Bbb N^{\Bbb Z} \to \Bbb N$ by 
$$
\Phi_N(g) = g(0)
$$
Define $\Phi(g) = (\Phi_Z(g),\Phi_N(g))$

Comment: Wow thats really nice, thanks! could you give some pointers on how to go on and prove that it's surjective? as i see it the surjective property depends on f or doesn't it?

Comment: The point is that we have *every* $f: \Bbb Z \to \Bbb N$ to choose from.  For each pair $(z,n)$, you just need **one** function $f$ such that $\Phi(f) = (z,n)$. I'll change it to $g$ to make it clearer.

Comment: I simplified the function a bit

Comment: ah yes of course, thank you!